# Generate form elements based on type, with overrides

Tags: java, javafx

With a few applications I'm building, I could use the ability to generate dynamic forms for filling in arbitrary lists of variables. For example, when running a Lua script that reads in an arbitrary file format, the script may need unique information to decode that format (e.g. separating character for a CSV). Essentially, I want something similar to [Unity](https://unity3d.com/)'s inspector.

I have a `HashMap` that maps a `Class` to a `Handler`:

```
private interface Handler {
    Control handle(GridPane grid, Integer row);
}

private static final HashMap<Class, Handler> FormInputs =
        new HashMap<Class, Handler>() {
    {
        // String
        put(String.class, (grid, row) -> CreateStringInput(grid, row));

        // Integer
        put(int.class, (grid, row) -> CreateIntegerInput(grid, row));
        put(Integer.class, (grid, row) -> CreateIntegerInput(grid, row));

        // Float
        put(float.class, (grid, row) -> CreateFloatInput(grid, row));

        // Directory
        put(Path.class, (grid, row) -> CreateFileInput(grid, row));
        put(File.class, (grid, row) -> CreateFileInput(grid, row));

    }
};
```

When the form is created, it uses `getFields()` to get the list of fields from the passed `Class`, and when the form is constructed, it creates a simple `GridPane` and fills it with labels and controls.

In theory, this should work fine, but I noticed with the `Path` class that the class does not always line up with its intended use. A `Path` may point to a file or a directory, which require different settings for the browsing dialog. Similarly, a `String` may be used for any number of things, and may need certain validation.

What would be the most friendly approach for overriding the type check and explicitly stating which form input to use? I looked into using Decorators, but those seem to be for extending existing functions of the decorated object, whereas I want to imbue them with extra information.

edit: For further context, I would like to be able to do things like Unity's [Range()] decorator, whereby numeric classes become represented by a slider between the min and max values.

edit 2: To clarify and simplify: The `Form` class generates an automatic form based on a class. For example, passing it the following class

```
public class TestClass {
    public boolean bool1;
    public Boolean bool2;
    public String string1;
    public String string2;
    public Integer int1;
    public int int2;
    public Path path1;
    public File file1;
}
```

results in the following form:

[image: Automatically generated form]

I want to be able to indicate, in the class, which fields should be handled differently. Ideally I also want this to work by passing in an array of mixed variables, and I want to be able to define a custom schema, like can be done with Unity and custom inspectors.

Comment: Could you please add more details on how you use FormInputs? This is what I understand: You have a class with several fields (values). Somewhere else, you have a mapping of data types with their render function. What you want to achieve is somehow extend the mapping for specific fields. Is that correct? If so, is this extension expected to be in the class containing the fields, the fields themselves (e.g., using Directory instead of Path, or even Directory<Path>), or the mapping?

Comment: @MiguelJiménez Does this further information help? I want to be able to indicate this information in the class, and/or with a custom inspector.

Comment: you can try to call a method getPropNameFormInputs() that return Node for example from the object, and if it does not exist use the default method(I can write an example of that). so in the object, all you need to do is use the right name and signature for the Custom FormInputs

Comment: ControlsFX's [`PropertySheet`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html) is probably worth a look. It should allow you to specify different kinds of editors for the properties...

Comment: @fabian Thank you, this looks like it might be precisely what I'm trying to make, which would save me considerable effort.

Comment: Actually no, this doesn't seem any more helpful. It's pretty much just a vague framework that does exactly what I've already written and no more. I would have to write my own classes that extend PropertySheet.Item and I would still have to detect which ones to use somehow, so... that doesn't really help with this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I have come up with involves a bit of rearranging. It only works automatically for custom classes, but it allows for some customisation after initialisation.

First, write a public interface for custom classes to implement that allows them to define a custom list of controls:

```
public interface FormLayout {
    List<Input> getLayout();
}
```

Then, in the constructor, instead of initialising a list of fields, check if the object defines its own layout:

```
public Form (Object objRef) {
    Field[] fields = objRef.getClass().getFields();
    if(objRef instanceof Form.FormLayout) {
        inputs = ((FormLayout) objRef).getLayout();
    }
    else {
        inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            inputs.add(new Input(fields[i].getName(), FormInputs.get(fields[i].getType())));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have a list of defined inputs that can be manipulated before constructing the form, and the ability to define a custom layout for a class.

Further work will need to be done to handle associating an input with a field so the user input actually makes its way to the right variable, but this seems to be the most reasonable approach.